# What is a good approach for classifying pairs of mutually dependent populations?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

Imagine you have several pairs of populations - **1a and 1b, 2a and 2b, ... , na and nb**. **'a'** denotes a normal population and **'b'** - an affected population. Populations **'a'** and **'b'** are mutually dependent in pairs, meaning the features of an affected population depend on the initial features of that population, i.e. a normal population. How to correctly classify the populations **1b, 2b,..., nb** using machine learning, if you're interested in comparing how different are the differences in each pair **'a'** and **'b'** rather than comparing diferences between the populations **'b'** directly? How to tranform the original covariates of the populations **'a' and 'b'**, so they represent both populations simultaneously?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. What should the output look like? Just give the classification of samples? Or name the differences between classes / pairs of classes?

Comment: Yes, the output I'm looking for is just the classification of the samples from the affected populations, based on how different they are from the corresponding unaffected populations.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a generative model of populations 1a + 1b, along with desired output.  
It's easy to evaluate a classifier if you _already_ know ground truth for some of its testing examples, since you know how you generated the example which must now be classified.

Comment: The thing is the populations 1b, 2b, 3b, etc. might be not that different, when compared directly, but if 1a, 2a, 3a are different, then there should be a way to classify 'b' populations based on how different they are from their corresponding 'a' populations. I thought about the hierarchical multi-label classification at first. However, transforming the covariate values of the pair of populations to have a single dataset, representing both populations simultaneously, seems interesting, but I'm not sure if there is a way to do that.